# The design config needs an area and a store. Verify that both are set and try again. Magento 2.3.3

Tags: smtp, magento2

Estoy probando la extension **SMTP de Mageplaza en Magento 2.3.3**, pero al realizar la prueba de envio obtengo el siguiente error:

**The design config needs an area and a store. Verify that both are set and try again.**

Validando los logs obtengo la siguiente linea:

**The design config needs an area and a store. Verify that both are set and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): The design config needs an area and a store. Verify that both are set and try again. at public_html/my_store/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php:622)"} []**

Y finalmente llendo a la linea antes mencionada:

```
public function setDesignConfig(array $config)
{
if (!isset($config['area']) || !isset($config['store'])) {
throw new LocalizedException(
__('The design config needs an area and a store. Verify that both are set and try again.')
);
}
$this->getDesignConfig()->setData($config);
return $this;
}
```

Alguien podría ayudarme, ya que llevo mas de una semana con este problema y casi no hay información en internet para resolverlo.

Gracias